# Increment SESSION amount PHP

Tags: php, arrays, session, increment

I'm using sessions to populate a simple shopping cart but, I'm having some problems getting the `itemAmount` to increment if an `item_id` already exists within the `session['cart']`.

I have been trying to increment here: `$itemAmount = $eachItem['itemAmount'];` but, can't get it working.

This is what I have at the moment;

***UPDATED;*** the code with better naming, I still need help with getting the cart_item_amount to increment, at the moment it creates a new item every time instead of incrementing the cart_item_amount.

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
// create the cart session
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}
?>
<?php
// if all posts are fine
if(isset($_POST['item_id'])) {

    // set post values
    $post_item_id = $_POST['item_id'];
    $post_item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $post_options = $_POST['item_options'];
    $post_item_extras = $_POST['item_extras'];

    // set initial item amount
    $item_total = 1;

    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $value) {

        if($value['cart_item_id'] == $post_item_id) {

            $value['cart_item_amount']++;
            $item_total = $value['cart_item_amount'];

        }else{

        }
    }
    // if option selected
    if(isset($post_options)) {

        // split to get two separate values
        list($post_item_cost, $post_option_name) = explode("-", $post_options, 2);

    }

    // loop through extras          
    if(isset($post_item_extras)) {

        foreach($post_item_extras as $key => $value) {

            // split to get two separate values
            list($post_extra_cost, $post_extra_name) = explode("-", $value, 2);

            // create extras array
            $item_extras[] = array(
                'cart_extra_cost' => $post_extra_cost,
                'cart_extra_name' => $post_extra_name
            );

        }
    }

    // add each item to an array
    $cart_row = array(
        'cart_item_id' => $post_item_id,
        'cart_item_name' => $post_item_name,
        'cart_option_name' => $post_option_name,
        'cart_item_cost' => $post_item_cost,
        'cart_item_amount' => $item_total,
        // add the extras array
        'cart_item_extras' => $item_extras 
    );

        // add new row to the session Cart
        $_SESSION['cart'][] = $cart_row;
}
?>

Array
(
    [cart] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [cart_item_id] => 76
                    [cart_item_name] => Cheese Burger
                    [cart_option_name] => Small
                    [cart_item_cost] => 1.00
                    [cart_item_amount] => 1
                    [cart_item_extras] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [cart_item_id] => 76
                    [cart_item_name] => Cheese Burger
                    [cart_option_name] => Small
                    [cart_item_cost] => 1.00
                    [cart_item_amount] => 2
                    [cart_item_extras] => 
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [cart_item_id] => 76
                    [cart_item_name] => Cheese Burger
                    [cart_option_name] => Small
                    [cart_item_cost] => 1.00
                    [cart_item_amount] => 3
                    [cart_item_extras] => 
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($eachItem['itemID'] = $_POST['item_id']) {
```

= is not a Comparison Operator, see
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

should be

```
if($eachItem['itemID'] == $_POST['item_id']) {
```

Comment: also use better names, $item_id is not obvious if there is also an $itemID, and $item_name and $itemName ...

Comment: thanks missed that, got it working now. I'm about to change up the naming, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by simply using this;

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $value) {

    if($value['cart_item_id'] == $post_item_id) {

         $_SESSION['cart'][$key]['cart_item_amount']++;

         return false;

}
```